# How to parse string containing negative number into integer?

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

Part of my code is here!

```
bufferedReader=new BufferedReader (inputstreamreader);
message=bufferedReader.readLine ();// ex: message has (1,-3)
String[] msg=message.split (",") //I use comma (,) as deliminator
int x=Integer.parseInt (msg [0]);
int y=Integer.parseInt (msg [1]);
```

This clearly parses but the problem is it looses negative sign. That is the "message" contains (1,-3). Pls help me to parse without loosing -ve sign.

Comment: your code seems fine. before splitting print what you have received may be some thing wrong at sending end.

Comment: Yea... the problem was at client end of socket!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String message = "1,-3";
String[] msg = message.split(",");
int x = Integer.parseInt(msg[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(msg[1]);

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
```

Works without a problem. Output:

> 1
>
> -3

Comment: Thanks... First I got NumberFormatException. Now I corrected it

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad I think you first got `double number`. That's why you got  `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

`ParseInt` Should work, however you are not getting the result because `String[] msg = message.split(",");` results in 2 strings with "(1" and other "-10)" try to remove the braces

Comment: Thanks bro! Actually the problem was it was a floating point number. Now I corrected it